# Slow Initialization and Inference Time with PyTorch and Pyannote on EC2 Instance Despite Caching

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pytorch

The following code, which uses `pytorch` and `pyannote` and runs a simple inference is taking a good amount of time to load on a freshly created `g4dn` EC2 instance using an Amazon Machine Image in which all these imports were cached and the model has already been run.

```
import time
import os

start_time = time.time()
from torch import device
from torch.cuda import is_available
print(f"torch import time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s")

start_time = time.time()
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
print(f"pyannote import time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s")

API_TOKEN = os.environ.get('API_TOKEN')

start_time = time.time()
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.1", use_auth_token=API_TOKEN)
if is_available():
    pipeline.to(device("cuda"))
print(f"model loading time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s")

start_time = time.time()
pipeout = pipeline('/home/ubuntu/diarisation/test_10s.wav')
print(f"model inference time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} s")
```

On the first run after the EC2 instance creation, these were the execution times:

```
# torch import time: 9.97 s
# pyannote import time: 13.39 s
# model loading time: 20.99 s
# model inference time: 25.85 s
```

Subsequent runs:

```
# torch import time: 1.34 s
# pyannote import time: 2.18 s
# model loading time: 1.95 s
# model inference time: 0.65 s
```

If I reboot the machine, it is also slowed down, but not as much as when I create a new EC2:

```
# torch import time: 3.11 s
# pyannote import time: 4.65 s
# model loading time: 2.84 s
# model inference time: 1.41 s
```

I wonder what could be causing that and if there is a way to speed that up? Is that specific to AWS?

I am on Ubuntu 22.04. Torch version: 2.1.2+cu121, Python 3.10.12. Torch installed using `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio`.

Comment: You should update py torch and latest Python 3.11.7. You will  get no error message.

Comment: I am not getting any error message at all. It's about the time it takes for the imports and the model to load.